# Learning and Understanding binary-machine

Tags: binary, machine-code

Each program consists of a binary system at the end of the day. So how do processors understand this complex code? Where can I find a list of patterns describing specific special situations?

I know I'm being ridiculous, and you probably don't understand. I'll try to explain right away.

Python code:
!!! I know the python code is not translated into machine language. (Ahh some people...)

```
a = 1

if a==1:
         a+=2
```

```
COMPARISON

PYTHON SYNTAX           MACHINE CODE                                  MEAN

a=1                     10010(a)  111(=) 1(value)                     define variable

if  a==1                101010(if) 10010(a) 111(=) 111(=) 1(value)    condition                     

a = a + 2             10010(a) 111(=) 10010(a) 101(+) 2(value)      increase the value of y by two
```

The above things are 100% wrong. But I think you understand what I want to say.

Comment: Take a look at assembly language and programming language theory. Basically, the human readable code is translated into instructions in a CPU-specific language. These consist of an OPCode that tells the CPU what to do, and register and/or RAM addresses. See how these instructions look like:
[a modern x86 CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), and
[a MIPS CPU with a smaller instruction set](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-f97/public/doc/mips-isa.pdf)

Unfortunately I am not sure if this question is appropriate for stackoverflow :/

Answer (score 0):

You're understanding it wrong.

When someone tells you that human readable code is translated into machine code, the code is not simply encoded AS-IS to the processor.  It is completely rewritten using instructions that the processor understands and supports.  This is why programs compiled to x32 or x64, or ARM are different and mostly incompatible (because each one support a different set of operations).

To illustrate this, imagine the executions of a simple `IF` statement, I am not aware of a processor that supports it directly (it may or not exist).  But all processors supports the conditional JUMP operation (eg. jump if zero, jump if not zero, etc), that is similar to the GOTO statement in some programming languages (the same that everybody says that it is a bad practice to use).

So, when you write something like:

```
if a == b:
  # do something

# next statement
```

In machine code, it is translated to something like this:

```
0001:               # this is the address of the code, just for reference
                    # each line has an address, even when not explicit written
                    # the size of each line depends of the instruction and the
                    # number of parameters it take
  MOV regA, a       # copy the contents of A from memory to a processor register named "regA"
  MOV regB, b       # copy the contents of B from memory to a processor register named "regB"
  SUB regA, regB    # runs subtration operation, with result stored in a special register
  JNZ 0100          # jump to address 0100 if the special register is NOT zero
  JMP 0050          # jump to address 0050 (unconditionally)
0050:
  # do something
  #
  JMP 0100          # jumo to address 0100 (unconditionally)
0100:
  # next statement
  #
```

Notice that, in the example code, we were comparing two variables.  But in machine code, it subtracts them and tests if the result is zero, instead.  If it is zero, they're equal.  If not, they're not equal.  I used this example just to demonstrate that machine code may be completely different of what we write using programming languages.

And how this is converted in zeros-and-ones?  Each operation is translated to an "opcode" that is the identification of that operation in that processor.

```
ADD -> 0000 0001  # the opcode may be different for different processors
SUB -> 0000 0010
MOV -> 0000 0011
...
```

After the opcode, we have the instruction's parameters.  The way parameters are passed may vary, but basically each processor register also have a identitication, and variables are actually memory addresses (which are numbers already).  So one instruction in machine code looks like:

```
 0000 0011    1010 1010    1110 1010 1111 0000
|_________|  |_________|  |___________________|
     |            |                   |
 MOV opcode    regA id        address of "a"
```

So, finishing this incredibly summarized explanation of how human readable code is translated to machine code, notice that machines only understand their language (which usually is a very limited set of basic arithmetic operations, jumps and hability to manipulate memory).  The main challenge of compilers/interpreters is to translate the language we wrote (with all cosmetics, like packages, classes, objects and so on) to the language that machines understand, without changing semantics.